# How to use `call()` with arguments that update?

Tags: r, eval, call

```
x <- 1
test_call <- call(">", x, 0)
eval(test_call)
[1] TRUE

x <- -1
eval(test_call)
[1] TRUE
```

I have a list of `call` objects that I want to evaluate from time to time. However, as shown in this example, when `test_call` is being called the 2nd time, the value of `x` is not updated within `test_call` - The 2nd output is expected to be `FALSE`.

I know I can get around by using `parse()` instead of `call()` but `parse()` really makes the code hard to read... Any workaround if I want to stick with `call`?

Comment: `test_call <- call(">", quote(x), 0)`

Comment: Could make your own function to do that too
`test_call <- function(x){eval(call(">", x, 0))}`